# How do I programatically collect packets from passively sniffing?

Tags: java, c++, macos, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I want to test the vulnerability of the server I just wrote against man in the middle attacks.

How (on Mac OS X) do I analyze packets. (I'll be checking where they are going, pulling information from if they are heading to my server, and seeing what all is available) Then I'll figure out a way to encrypt everything... but first things first.

Any help on packet sniffing would be greatly appreciated.

My preferred language is java.
But I can do C++.

so, my question is: "Is there any sort of API / library that I can interface with?"

Like, if I could do PacketSniffer ps = new PacketSniffer(); that would be amazing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best portable library for this is [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/).  There's even a [java wrapper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jnetpcap/) available for it.

Answer (score 4):

No need to write your own - Download Wireshark from http://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: is there a way I could interface with it from a program I write?

Comment: like, how would I get the packets into my code to analyze?

Comment: Yes. You can access the packet capture library, libpcap.  Wireshark uses libpcap to do the actual capture.

Answer (score 0):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and [KisMAC](http://trac.kismac-ng.org/) both offer source code downloads and run on MacOS X. You can strip the needed code from there (if it's just for your internal use).

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to libcrafter: http://code.google.com/p/libcrafter/

The library has a Sniffer class with an interface very easy to use:

http://code.google.com/p/libcrafter/wiki/SnifferIntroduction